# Transforming list into array and after that joining it with another array results in error

Tags: python, arrays, list, join, transformation

I want to join two arrays. The first array called "results_array" used to be a `list(1dim)` and I'm using 
asarray to transform it into an array. It should result in an array with the dimension `(50,1)`, but it actually results in a `(50,)` kind of array I don't know what that means. Then I wanted to use concatenate to join it with another array(columnwise), array1, which actually has the dimension `(50,1)`.

This is my code:

```
results_array=np.asarray(results)
final= np.concatenate((array1, results_array), axis=1)
```

Then I get the following error message:

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

What can I do about this? Thanks in advance

Comment: post array examples and code to reproduce problem

Answer (score 2):

Instead of asarray function, you can build an array with the array constructor, *ie*

```py
results_array = np.array([results])
print (results_array.shape)
>>> (1, 50)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your results array is a 1D array, giving the dimension only one element `(50,)`.  If you want to concatenate, you will need to reshape it to have the correct dimensions.

```
final = np.concatenate([array1, results_array.reshape(-1, 1)], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

you need the same 1D arrays for concatenation
Try .flatten() to make your array1 to make it 1D

```
results_array=np.asarray(results)
final= np.concatenate((array1.flatten(), results_array))
```